# using the clock of FPGA in system generator

Tags: fpga, clock, xilinx-system-generator, fifo

I have designed a circuit in system generator. I am using a FIFO at the output. I want to connect the *we* pin of FIFO to the clock of FPGA, but I do not know how should I do it in ***System Generator***. In another language how can I access to the clock of FPGA in ***System Generator.*** Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen at least two ways to use System Generator:

1. Within Simulink, run all the way through synthesis and implementation and produce a .bit file
2. Convert the System Generator design to the two VHDL files *yourdesign*.vhd and *yourdesign*_cw.vhd. Then run synthesis and implmentation in ISE or Vivado after importing the VHDL files into your project and tying the ports manually.

I'm not sure if what you're asking is possible if you're using method 1. However if you're using method 2, you can always connect the *we* input of the FIFO to a yellow input block, then when you place your auto-generated VHDL component into your top-level design, you can tie the clock to the *we* port you created.